# How to send parameters to AJAX POST method of another PHP website and fetch JSON information

Tags: php, ajax, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am researching on "*how to parse the content from other website*". I am using **HTML DOM parsing** to fetch the information. Problem i am facing is with websites which contains **AJAX POST** calls to fetch the information. Example website: [Massachussets](http://www.massgeneral.org/doctors/)

1.Here doctors information is fetched using ajax post method

```
Request URL:http://www.massgeneral.org/assets/javascripts/facets/doctors/doctors.ashx
Request Method:POST
```

How do i pass the parameters to post methods here?. What i tried is

```
<?php
echo '<center><h3>Massachusetts Information</h3></center>';
// extra headers
//$headers[]= "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$fields['center'] = "";
$fields['centerPreSelected'] = false;
//$fields['displayPaging'] = false;
$fields['gender'] = "";
$fields['isEmpty'] = true;
$fields['languages'] = [];
$fields['letter'] = "A";
$fields['letter'] = "";
$fields['locations'] = array();
$fields['numberOfPages'] = 15;
$fields['numberPerPage'] = 50;
$fields['page'] = 1;
$fields['program'] = "";
$fields['range'] = array('Item1' => 0,'Item2' => 49);
$fields['saytLimit'] = "20";
$fields['term'] = "";

$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields);

$headers[] = "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*";
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5";
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Host: www.massgeneral.org";
$headers[]="Referer: http://www.massgeneral.org/doctors/";

$login_submit_url = "http://www.massgeneral.org/assets/javascripts/facets/doctors/doctors.ashx";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

It did not fetched the doctors information.
Please provide links or idea to parse it.

Comment: What you want to extract in that information? Have you tried `DOMDocument`?

Comment: Nope.This i heard for first time.I want to retrieve all doctors information from that site.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to scrape the content of a website, but that website uses AJAX to populate its content. So when you use cURL to get the website's content, it's missing the content populated by AJAX, and you want to know how to get that.. right?

Comment: @Nick Coons .Exactly !...I think i m missing some parameters to send while calling AJAX POST

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for a particular site where the AJAX call is known ahead of time, or for any given site that may contain such a call?

Comment: To any given site contain such call. I picked [Massechusets](http://www.massgeneral.org/doctors/) as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `http_build_query()` which creates a "foo=1&bar=2" style format. The site is expecting json so you want to use `json_encode()` instead.

Also, leave out the gzip header unless you're sure you really want to deal with a gzipped response.

Comment: When i replaced `http_build_query()` with `json_encode()` it return output like this : ���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?...................can you please suggest where all i need to make changes in my code?

Comment: Take out the gzip header. It's sending you a gzipped response because that's what you asked for.